# Como ajustar los divs a la pantalla

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente código js para cuando se lance la pagina web se ajuste a la pantalla todos los divs, pero falla algo y no me funciona, pueden ayudarme

```js
function oWeb(){
  var alto = document.getElementById.offsetHeight; // aca hay un error, no hace ref a nada
  document.getElementById('marcoIzq').style.height = alto -125 + "px";
  document.getElementById('marcoCentro').style.height = alto -125 + "px";
  document.getElementById('marcoDer').style.height = alto -125 + "px";
}
```

Comment: deberías agregar el código completo vara ver donde haces el llamado de la función.

Comment: Mediaqueries bro, revisa sobre mediaqueries y eso va en el CSS y se feliz :D bienvenido a SOes por cierto, recuerda visitar https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso obtengas tu primera medalla :D

Comment: El error te da porque no le estás pasando ningún id al `document.getElementById` (¿quizás lo quieres hacer de toda la ventana?). Habría que ver el resto de tu código (en especial el html y css), pero parece que lo que quieres es que las columnas tengan un alto del alto de la ventana menos 125 pixeles, en cuyo caso podrías plantearte usar flex o similares y no tendrías problemas con el JS.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar media queries, acá te dejo una fuente muy buena: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Ejemplos:

```
/* For mobile phones: */
[class*="col-"] {
  width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  /* For tablets: */
  .col-s-1 {width: 8.33%;}
  .col-s-2 {width: 16.66%;}
  .col-s-3 {width: 25%;}
  .col-s-4 {width: 33.33%;}
  .col-s-5 {width: 41.66%;}
  .col-s-6 {width: 50%;}
  .col-s-7 {width: 58.33%;}
  .col-s-8 {width: 66.66%;}
  .col-s-9 {width: 75%;}
  .col-s-10 {width: 83.33%;}
  .col-s-11 {width: 91.66%;}
  .col-s-12 {width: 100%;}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  /* For desktop: */
  .col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
  .col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
  .col-3 {width: 25%;}
  .col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
  .col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
  .col-6 {width: 50%;}
  .col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
  .col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
  .col-9 {width: 75%;}
  .col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
  .col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
  .col-12 {width: 100%;}
}
```

Te salvaras del abismo.

Comment: Gracias por apoyar. Por favor lee [answer], edita tu aporte y amplia pues solo responder con enlaces se considera de baja calidad

Comment: @element listo.